# Which program should get the higher priority for dispatching the CPU? Why?

Tags: cpu

Given two programs that are multiprogrammed in a single processor computer:
Program ONE uses a large amount of CPU time and little I/O.
Program TWO uses a small amount of CPU time but performs a large number of I/O operations.
Which program should get the higher priority for dispatching the CPU? Why?

Comment: Where do I submit my answers and how much credit do I get?

Answer (score 0):

The second (IO-intensive one) should have highest priority: it has small impact on CPU and while it waits for IO completion the other process, the CPU-intensive, could do its job.

Then, when the IO is completed, the second task gets its chance to treat the IO result and post another IO request, then it is swapped out again in favor of CPU-intensive process.

Answer (score 0):

Shortest Remaining Time First Scheduling should be used.

Otherwise there will be [Convoy Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I/O_bound) check "Comparison with CPU-bound" on the mentioned webpage.

There is a convoy effect as the I/O bound process wait for the one big CPU bound process to get off the CPU. This effect results in lower CPU and device utilization than might be possible if the shorter CPU bound process is allowed to go first.